# Чего не хватает в Python коде Телеграм бота c БД sqlite3? (ошибка: cannot commit - no transaction is active )

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite3

При одновременном нажатии с двух телефонов на кнопку Получения баланса (`elif call.data == 'balance':`) иногда выскакивает ошибка (в Боте: ❌ Ошибка !), а в консоли: `cannot commit - no transaction is active`

Чего не хватает в Python коде Телеграм бота c БД sqlite3 или может есть ошибки? conn.commit() cur.close()  conn.close() и т.д.

В (elif call.data == 'balance': ... else: ) не хватает conn.commit() ?

ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЯ К БД В "DEF" НЕТУ ИЛИ НУЖНО В КАЖДОМ подключать? Лишний код скрыл.

Возможно где-то лишний cur = conn.cursor().

```
    def process_name_pass_down_balance(message):
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('⬅️ Вернуться.', callback_data='hozyin')
        markup.add(btn1)
        id = message.text
        balance_id[message.from_user.id] = id
        sql_select_query = """select * from clients where userid = ?"""
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql_select_query, (id,))
        record = cur.fetchall()[0]
        msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,f'Баланс этого пользователя {record[1]}\nНа какую сумму желаете его уменьшить?',reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_name_pass_down_balance_set)
    
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def callback_inline(call):
                //ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЯ К БД В ЭТОМ КОЛБЕКЕ НЕТУ ИЛИ НУЖНО В КАЖДОМ КОЛБЕКЕ
                try:
                    elif call.data == 'balance':
                        markup4 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                        btn5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("⬅️ Вернуться в Личный кабинет", callback_data='lk')
                        markup4.add(btn5)
                        sql_select_query = """select * from clients where userid = ?"""
                        cur = conn.cursor()
                        cur.execute(sql_select_query, (call.from_user.id,))
                        records = cur.fetchall()
                        if len(records) == 0:
                            sqlite_update_query = """Update clients set balance = ? where userid = ?"""
                            cur = conn.cursor()
                            cur.executemany(sqlite_update_query, [(0, call.from_user.id)])
                            conn.commit()
                            bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, f'Баланс Личного кабинета: 0 грн.', reply_markup=markup4)
                        else:
                            bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, f'Баланс Личного кабинета: {round(float(records[0][1]),2)} грн.', reply_markup=markup4)
            
                    elif call.data == "King":
                        code = generate_code()
                        sql_select_query = """select * from cham where userid = ?"""
                        cur = conn.cursor()
                        cur.execute(sql_select_query, (call.from_user.id,))
                        records = cur.fetchall()[0]
                        if len(records) == 0:
                            data = (call.from_user.id, 0, code, 'UAH')
                            cur = conn.cursor()
                            cur.execute("INSERT INTO cham VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);", data)
                            conn.commit()
                        else:
                            sqlite_update_query = """Update cham set code_c = ? where userid = ?"""
                            cur = conn.cursor()
                            cur.executemany(sqlite_update_query, [(code, call.from_user.id)])
                            conn.commit()
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, f'❌ Ошибка !',reply_markup=markup_leave)
    while True:
            try:
                bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0, timeout=25)
            except:
                pass
```